# Removing a product from the collection on a category

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, product-collection

I have a Magento site where I need to remove some products from certain customer groups due to them having a zero price on the products.

I have tried `catalog_product_collection_load_after` event and have successfully managed to remove the products that I want. This however causes a gap on the catagory pages where the products would be. Would there be any way to go about remove products from a collection either before the pagination is set on the collection or to "remake" the collection once you've removed the products.

The code I've tried so far:

```
 /* Remove all products from the category list where the (group) price is zero */
public function removeZeroPriceProducts($observer) {

    if (! Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())
    {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        //Loop through all products in the collection
        foreach ($collection as $product)
        {

            $origProduct = $product;

            //If it is a configurable we need to get the childrens prices.
            // Since if the customer isn't allowed to see the product all prices on all children will be zero we only need to get any of the children
            if($this->getTypeId() == "configurable") {
                $product = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('price')->addPriceData()->setPageSize(1)->getFirstItem();
            }

            //Check if the price is zero. If so remove the product from the collection. Note that this --will-- cause a gap in the end of the page before the pagination.
            if($origProduct->getFinalPrice() === 0 || $product->getFinalPrice() === 0)
                $observer->getEvent()->getCollection()->removeItemByKey($origProduct->getId());
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
I've tried added it to _getProductCollection in List.php as suggested by Mohit.
This removes the product as expected but unfortunately still leaves a gap. I'll leave the code for that here as well.

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $layer = $this->getLayer();
        /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
        if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
            $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
        }

        // if this is a product view page
        if (Mage::registry('product')) {
            // get collection of categories this product is associated with
            $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                ->setPage(1, 1)
                ->load();
            // if the product is associated with any category
            if ($categories->count()) {
                // show products from this category
                $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
            }
        }

        $origCategory = null;
        if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
            if ($category->getId()) {
                $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            }
        }
        $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

        $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

        if ($origCategory) {
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
        }
    }

    //Try and remove a specific ID from the collection
    $collection = $this->_productCollection;
    $collection->removeItemByKey(4146);
    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work.
On the `customer_login` event I loop through all the products and add all the products that the customer are not allowed to see into an array that I then save in a customer session variable.

I then create a function called `removeZeroPriceProducts` that catches onto the `catalog_product_collection_load_before` event. In this function I've excluded the products by doing the following:

```
/* Remove all products from the category list where the (group) price is zero */
public function removeZeroPriceProducts($observer) {

    if (! Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())
    {
        //Get all disallowed products for the user
        if($disallowed = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getDisallowedProducts()){
            //Add a filter for the product collection that removes all the disallowed products
            $observer->getEvent()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $disallowed));
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using `removeItemByKey` which removed the product but left a gap I now instead add a filter which removes all products that can be found in my session variable.

> Note. I first tried to loop through all the products in the **removeZeroPriceProducts** fonction. This however broke the page which is why I instead added all the products to a session variable when the customer logs in

Answer (score 0):

To modify product collection before rendering category page follow these steps:

> 1. Override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
> 2. In function _getProductCollection after if statement insert your code:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollection;
foreach ($collection as $k => $product){
 // Here goes your code to modify product
 // For example:

$collection->removeItemByKey($k);// Remove original item from collection 
}
$collection->setOrder('position','ASC');// Reorder collection as you want
return $collection;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: By ListProduct I'm guessning you meant List.php? I tried moving my code there but I still get a gap at the end of the page. Where in the function would I be adding the code? I tried a few different places with the same result

Comment: There is no file called ListProduct.php in Magento 1.7. I've overridden the code, that's not the issue. The issue is that I'm still getting the gap which is what I'm trying to prevent :)

Comment: Yes in Magento 1.7 there is List.php where you need to add this code. 
but am not getting what gap you are talking about ?

Comment: Can you show me your code in _getProductCollection function ?

Comment: Added it as an edit to my post.